# Laplace Transform of Riesz Fractional Derivative

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, fractional-calculus

I wanted to calculate the Laplace Transform of Riesz Fractional Derivative. But got some troubles in the middle.

The Riesz Fractional Derivative is given by:

$R^{\alpha}f(t)=-\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\omega|^{\alpha}F(\omega)e^{j\omega t}d\omega$

So I tried to took the Laplace Transform of it:

$ \mathcal{L}[R^\alpha f(t)] = -\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left [ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\omega|^\alpha F(\omega)e^{j\omega t} d\omega \right] e^{-st} dt $

Applying integration by parts, I assumed:

$ u = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\omega|^\alpha F(\omega)e^{j\omega t} d\omega $

$\frac{du}{d\omega} = |\omega|^\alpha F(\omega) e^{j\omega t} $

And

$ dv = e^{-st}$

$v = -\frac{e^{-st}}{s}$

So, I got this:

$ \mathcal{L}[R^\alpha f(t)] = -\frac{1}{2\pi} \left [ \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\omega|^\alpha F(\omega) e^{j\omega t} d\omega \right) \left ( - \frac{e^{-st}}{s} \right )_{-\infty}^{\infty} + \frac{1}{s} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\omega|^\alpha F(\omega) e^{j\omega t} e^{-st} dt \right] $

And I can't find a way to solve this, the both parts, i.e. I can't understand a way to evaluate the first term so as the second. My guess is that the $|\omega|^{\alpha}F(\omega)e^{j\omega t}$ is my function which will be used to compute the Laplace Transform. If this is correct, the problem is the first term, how to compute it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you defined $R^\alpha f(t)$ it is the inverse Laplace transform of $-(-s^2)^{\alpha/2}\mathcal{L}[F](s)$

Comment: How did you find this result @reuns

Comment: I meant $\mathcal{L}[f](s)$. This is the definition of the inverse Laplace transform. That $-(-s^2)^{\alpha/2}\mathcal{L}[f](s)$ is then the Laplace transform of $R^\alpha f(t)$ is the Fourier/Laplace inversion theorem.

Comment: So, just for me understood everything: $R^{a} f(t) = -(-s^{2})^{\frac{\alpha}{2}} \mathcal{L}[f](s)$ where $f$ is $f(t)$, not the $|\omega|^{\alpha} F(\omega)$. Thanks for everything!